# Copying a web part to /all/ pages?

Tags: web-part, navigation

I've created a right sidebar (summary links) on the page - for now, we'd like every single page on the site (>300) to have this, and then for certain pages to be customised (a few links added/removed depending on the page, but they'll mostly be the same) and I was wondering what the best way is of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

First: you created an own webpart? Didn't the out of the box summary links control cover your needs? Do you want to provision all links when the webpart is added, or will you be doing it manually?

assuming that you build the webpart yourself and didn't use the standard functionality, you have a few possibilities here:

1. Masterpage. Every page uses the same settings and, thus, the same links. Not editable via the browser. Doesn;t cover your requirement that certain pages need other links to be showed.
2. page layout. manage the links on a Per page layout basis. Not editable via the browser.
3. per page. Insert your webpart on all pages via script/code. This can be done via .Net code or powershell. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353460/how-to-add-custom-webparts-to-pages-in-powershell-scripts for *a* solution.

for more information on the standard summary links control, see: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/add-a-list-of-summary-links-to-a-publishing-page-layout-HA010174138.aspx

Comment: Many thanks for the reply! Yes it's just a summary links part, sorry if I wasn't very clear on that - I've just added a title and 4 links to a summary links part, but would like that on every page. It needs to be editable in the browser so looks like the powershell idea is the best way to do this